# Proof of the derivative of $b^T X^T X c$ in the matrix cookbook equation (77)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I am trying to study some matrix derivatives in the matrix cookbook. I am having trouble taking the derivative of $b^T X^T X c$ with respect to $X$.

Also if anyone can point me to some good resources that I can learn from, that would be great. The matrix cookbook is good for reference but without proofs I don't think I am learning from it.

The problem I am trying to prove is as follows,

$$
\frac{\partial \ \boldsymbol{b^T X^T X c}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}} =\boldsymbol{X}(\boldsymbol{bc^T +cb^T})
$$

I tried to use the chain rule ( I am unsure if there is a rule for if the inner derivative or the outer derivative comes first with matrices),

$$
\frac{\partial \ \boldsymbol{b^T X^T X c}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}} = \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{b^T X^T X c}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X^T X}} \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X^T X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}
$$

Then we know,

$$
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{b^T X^T X c}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X^T X}} = \boldsymbol{b c^T}
$$

So then the total expression becomes

$$
\frac{\partial \ \boldsymbol{b^T X^T X c}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}} = \boldsymbol{b c^T} \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{X^T X}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}
$$

But I am unsure how to calculate that partial derivative and it doesn't look like that this right anyhow. If anyone can provide me a proof or some references that would be nice. Thanks!

Update:
For an update and reference to go with accepted answer I want to include that the chain rule for a matrix derivative of a scalar function $f(U)$ is as shown below,

$$
\frac{\partial f(U)}{\partial X} = \frac{Tr((\frac{\partial f(U)}{ \partial U})^T \partial U)}{\partial X}
$$

This is shown in the matrix cookbook equation (213).

Comment: I think if you're unsure you should just try deriving it by index notation. Note that $b^T X^T X c$ is just a scalar, write it out in terms of the elements of $x_{ij}$ and then look at the derivative of your function with respect to each $x_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Use the known gradient to write the *differential* of the function,
which can then be expanded and rearranged to recover the desired gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{\LR{X^TX}} &= G \\
df &= G:d\LR{X^TX} \\
 &= G:\LR{X^TdX+dX^TX} \\
 &= {XG}:dX + {XG^T}:dX \\
 &= X\LR{G+G^T}:dX \\
\grad{f}{X} ​&= X\LR{G+G^T} \\\\
}$$

---

In the preceding, a colon is used to denote the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
such a product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A = A^TC:B \\\\
}$$